# X++ container to CSV string

Tags: csv, axapta, x++

I was wondering whether a container with values such as ["abc", 50, myDate, myRealNumber] can be converted to "abc","50","1/1/1900","-50.34" using a single function.

The con2Str global function fails if the input type is anything other than str.

I tried creating my own version of con2str function to use an "anyType" instead of str, but it fails because anyType cannot be assigned a different type after the first assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If such a function exists (it does not), it would have to deal with strings containing quotes etc.

This is all handled in class [CommaIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/commaio.aspx) method [writeExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/commaio.writeexp.aspx).
But it writes to a file of cause.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem with `anytype` you could use the class `SysAnyType` which wraps your value in another object so that multiple assignments are possible.